# In wso2 identity server how validate Ouath2 token and get user attributes

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

In wso2 identity server 5.10.0 after getting the access token I wanted to validate the OAuth2 token to check whether active or inactive then after the validation I wanted to get the user attributes(claims) for the user by token. How can I get as I got to know SOAP API is there for token validation (https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/oauth-token-validation-using-soap-service/ ) , but it return only token validation result, it won't return any extra information about the user attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OpenId connect userinfo endpoint to get the user attributes.

```
curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer <Acess_token>" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid
```

When requesting the token you should ask for the openid scope for the token.

https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/basic-client-profile-with-playground/